# Structural induction in haskell

Tags: induction, recursion

Notation in this question derives from Haskell as follows. Let $[A]$ denote the collection of lists whose elements are drawn from the set $A$, so e.g. $[\mathbb{Z}]$ is the set of integer lists. Denote the empty list of any type by $[]$. Denote a single-element list by by $[a]$. We may write any nonempty list as `a:x`, where $a \in A$ is the first element and $x \in [A]$ is the (possibly empty) tail of the list. Denote list concatenation by `a ++ b`. Lists are finite and allow repetitions: `1 : [1]` is a valid list, which has two elements ($1$ and $1$).

The Haskell code is:

```
perm :: [Int] -> [[Int]] 
perm z = f([], [], z) where  
f(x, y, []) = []   
f(x, [], [a]) = [x ++ [a]]  
f(x, y, a:z) = f(x ++ [a], [], y ++ z) ++ f(x, y ++ [a], z)
```

How do I prove that the function returns a permutation by using structural induction?

Comment: Whoever voted to close this, the question is manifestly about mathematics. It's asking whether a recursively-defined function is well-defined.

Comment: How does `z = f([], [], z)` work?  I'm not familiar with Haskell.  Can you give a comment of each line of code?

Comment: Perhaps someone can give a group-theoretical proof of this function's correctness; after all, it returns all permutations, a group!

Comment: It's `perm z` which equals to `f([], [], z)` *by definition*, written in a similar manner as in math (but without necessary parenthesis).

Comment: I gave a rundown of Haskell's notation at the top.

Comment: Why the necessity to have both `a:x` as well as `a ++ x`?

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint The first one adds an element to the beginning of the list and the second one concatenates two lists together.

Comment: @RollupandsmokeAdjoint `a:x` is precisely the constructor for a list with `a` prepended to the existing list `x`. The concatenation operation `++` is inefficient: it requires traversing the first list. What you wrote (`a ++ x`) does not type-check: you're concatenating an element with a list.

Comment: Some aspects of your explanation may seem evident to you but escape the understanding of your Readers.  Are lists finite?  Do they allow repetitions?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an expository hint than anything; I'm answering the "how" rather than giving an answer to the exercise.

You need to find an appropriate wellfounded partial order on $[\mathbb{Z}] \times [\mathbb{Z}] \times [\mathbb{Z}]$, such that the following relations hold for all lists $x, y, z \in [\mathbb{Z}]$ and for all $a \in \mathbb{Z}$:

```
(x ++ [a], [], y ++ z) < (x, y, a:z)
(x, y ++ [a], z) < (x, y, a:z)
```

In fact, the actual *elements* of the list are unimportant; your definition is completely generic on the type $\mathbb{Z}$. So we should be able to answer this question by only considering the lengths of the lists.
In fact, an equivalent formulation of your question is: prove by induction that $g : \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ is well-defined, where $g$ is given by

- $g(a, b, 0) = 0$
- $g(a, 0, 1) = 1$
- $g(a, b, c+1) = g(a+1, 0, b+c) + g(a, b+1, c)$.

(Moreover, you actually also want $g(0, 0, c) = c!$, but that's a story for another time.)

The way to do this is to find a function $i : \mathbb{N}^3 \to \mathbb{N}$ such that $i(a+1, 0, b+c) < i(a, b, c+1)$ (so that the first recursive call can be assumed inductively to terminate) and such that $i(a, b+1, c) < i(a, b, c+1)$ (so that the second recursive call can be assumed inductively to terminate). Once you've done this, you're done by induction on the value of $i$.

Comment: How do I prove the last element in the list is the reverse of the z?